# Adding Custom data Annotation using value from radio button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I am working on a sample project as my learning process. So in my project I am having an **IsActive** field which is a radio button . It will give either true or false. So if Is Active is False I have to make some fields mandatory like Reason,Remarks etc.I tried so many things but nothing is working for me.I am not understanding what all things I have to modify and also the places where I should modify

. I am working on MVC and consider my knowledge is low. And I have to do it as  model validation so custom data annotation is what I want. Any help will be appreciated.

I created a cs file like

```
public  class IsActiveTrue : ValidationAttribute
    {

  public override bool IsValid(object value)
  {
      var item = (Pen)value;
      if (item.IsActive == false)
      {
          if (item.ReportNo == null || item.Reason == null || item.Remarks == null)
          {
              return false;
          }
          else
          {
              return true;
          }
      }
      else
      {
          return true;
      }
  }
}
```

and in model

```
 [IsActiveTrue(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Requried")]
       public string Remarks { get; set; }
```

I am having message in the resourcse but the code is not working. please let me know wheather i am even near to the solution.

Comment: What is you `RequiredIfAttribute` and why are you registering it? Consider a `[foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfFalse]` or similar validation attribute, or if you want to write your own, refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: I am also not quite sure anyway tanx for the link